# Get data from XML by Google SheetS ImportXML function

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape data from XML with the function `IMPORTXML` of Google sheet but the return is empty.

I tried these formulae:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.futbin.com/20/player/42955/", "//span[@id='ps-lowest-1']/text()")
```

---

```
=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.futbin.com/20/player/42955/" , "//div[@class='xbox-lowest-1']"),1,1)
```

---

```
= IMPORTXML("https://www.futbin.com/20/player/42955/", "//*[@id='xbox-lowest-1']")
```

---

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.futbin.com/20/player/42955/", "//*[@id='xbox-lowest-1']/text()")
```

[image: I'm trying to extract this value]

Maybe the data is generated after by a script or something else.

Comment: The data on that page is dynamically loaded from another page using jscript. You can get to it using python libraries like requests, but I don't know if you can then load that directly to your sheet using importxml. You may have to write it to a csv file and then import it.

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
=QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://www.futbin.com/20/player/42955/"), 5000, 1), 
 "where lower(Col1) contains 'lowest'")
```

[image: 0]

but as you can see there are no numeric values in between those tags because Google Sheets does not support web scraping of JavaScript elements

Comment: Thank you for your replay. How I can achieve my goal ? (with another language ?)